# Windows Server 2012 R2 RD Web Access Redirect

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, rdweb

To start, I'm completely new to Server 2012, RD Web Access, and ASP.NET. I recently graduated college so I'm attempting this for the experience. I have a basic web dev background(HTML,CSS, Javascript, PHP, and MySQL). I have been asked to find a way to customize the Default.aspx and Desktops.aspx pages of RD Web Access based on the Active Directory domain a user logs in from. So if someone from Company A logs in with someone@companyAdomain.com, they are directed to a page customized for them. If someone from Company B logs in, they will be directed to a site customized for them, and so on. I've gone through the tutorials for customizing the single instance of Default/Login/Desktops so I get that. What I can't find is a way to make this modular, in that I wouldn't have to modify an if else statement every time a new company is added to redirect to their customized page.

Thank you!

Comment: Customized look and feel, or customized application list?

Comment: @Linuxx, ideally both. But to start, the customized look and feel for each company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files for the web access site are located in %windir%\web\rdweb\pages\en-us (for US English) on the gateway server. They are written in C# and html. If you are efficient in OO PHP you should be able to modify them. You would need to hard code some group names, and present a different CSS based upon that. Or, perhaps you string split the UPN, and throw the domain name into a switch statement.

I wouldn't recommend modifying these files, you never know what security vulnerabilities you are introducing. Additionally, I don't know how upgrade safe it would be.

Different icons would be configured in the collection settings.